# Is it Ok to do this? Store all variables in datagridview

Tags: xml, vb.net, datagridview, formatting

sorry if this is a silly question but I am still learning the No Nos of programing.

I am creating an application that handles a fair amount of data that is stored in an xml file.

The xml file file is formatted in this format

```
<Name>
   <Property_1></Property_1>
   <Property_2></Property_2>
   <Property_3></Property_3>
</Name>
```

There are about 16 properties per name and a lot of names.

What I am currently doing is importing all of that data from the xml file to the datagridview, and hiding the columns that the user doesn't need to see. And I am doing all the manipulation using the data in the datagridview.

Is it ok to do this or would be it better to get only the required data and do constant reads from the xml file?

For Example:
When a user makes a selection, right now I use a for each loop to look through all the rows  and make only the matching rows visible.

Or Should It be so that when a user makes a selection the program looks for all the matching criteria in the xml file and load all the data into the grid view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an approach that is fine for very small applications. However, it is generally accepted that you should separate your UI and Business Logic. The main reason for this is to handle the complexity of larger applications, through a proper structure.

For something other that a throw away demo, I would create a "Name" object and add all the properties (Property_1 etc.) plus a Visible property, and you would need a collection (list?) to hold them. Then you could have a method that sets the visible property (or passes in the search criteria and allows the object to set it itself) on all the objects and another that returns only visible objects. You can databind the grid to the objects.

There are frameworks available to do some of the work for you but i am fairly certain they would be overkill in this situation as they have a steep learning curve.

If you are using WPF then I strongly suggest you read up on MVVM. 
good luck

Comment: Thank you very much for the info!

This is simply for in house use, to help speed up the process, the only reason I choose this way was because it seemed easier and more efficient.

I felt that with constant reads from an xml file, the program would be more likely to throw exceptions and the constant reads would also result in slower performance. Is this correct? Or incorrect logic?

Comment: Reading data from memory is thousands of times faster than from disk, whether this matters or not is another question. The longer you program the better a sense you should get for what is "easier and more efficient" in the long term. A skill that you develop while struggling with a design may be worth the extra time it took. Of course nobody is going to thank you for taking a week to code something when an afternoon should have done.